# IE max-width and max-height issue on wrapped images

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Can't resolve this issue. In other browsers everything goes fine, but IE ignores max-height rule for wrapped images. The idea is that image should fit to the fixed full-sized container (`.wrap`), and image container (`.container`) should have the same size as image.

For example, i have such code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
            .wrap {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            .container {
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
            }
            .container img {
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <img alt="Image" src="image_bigger_than_a_viewport.jpg">
            </div>
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where source image should be bigger than a viewport size to let it scale down (you can just scale down browser window size).

Thank you.

UPD. Live demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/egGQ7/show/

Comment: Can create a fiddle ??

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/egGQ7/. Working fine in IE9, IE10

Comment: jsfiddle has another wrappers and frame that emulates window so it work in edit mode. But if you'll look for it in the show mode, you'll see what i'm talking about: http://fiddle.jshell.net/egGQ7/show/